# Why does the default view for a List in ASP.NET MVC use 'var' to iterate through the items?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The title pretty much sums it up, it puts the following line of code in:

```
 <% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
```

As the View is auto-generated and uses reflection to work out exactly what item is, so you get intellisense and everything, I just wonder, why do they use var rather than the actual type?

Comment: Saves them the trouble of printing out the type. That code you have there will work for any type in Model.

Comment: True, but the rest of the autogenerated code won't, as it basically writes code to output all of the properties of the object to the screen. If anything it makes it more likely you will pass an item of the wrong type and thus break it.

Comment: @SLC, It isn't more likely to break just because you use var instead of the explicit type. The compiled code will be the same ether way. It will always break as soon as you pass the wrong type to a typed view.

Comment: @Mattias, if you use var, it means you can call the view with any data. If you explicitly type it, it will stop you from accidentally calling a view with invalid data by immediately flagging it as an error in the IDE.
Also, ironically, the book I am learning MVC switched it from Var to the actual type without mentioning it... the examples suddenly changed with no explanation. I guess it really doesn't matter after all.

Comment: @SLC you seem to have a misunderstanding of what the var keyword does.  It is compile-time syntactic sugar.  It does not make the code more or less strongly typed than specifying the type explicitly.

Comment: @SLC, You still type the view to the correct type. You can't type a view to var. Just because you use var in a loop in the view doesn't mean that it isn't typed. So no, there is no difference in what errors you will get if you pass the wrong data to the view.

Comment: I understand now, thanks. I can't accept your explanation as the answer though because it's a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I like the `var` statement and consider it a great addition to the C# language. It is just one less place to worry about when I decide to change the type. I also try to follow the DRY principle, why repeat the type of the variable when it is already in the strongly typed view definition?

But I guess it is a matter of personal preference whether or not to use `var`.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider it best practice to always use var. I think that is more readable. My guess is that microsoft feels the same way.

Comment: I know many think this way, but I think var makes code harder to read.  I run into code examples in books and blogs that use 'var' and there is no possible way to figure out what the types are.  In a full program, I'll often have to consult the item definition.  'var' is *required* for anonymous types though.

Comment: @kervin, It is just my personal opinion. In the end it doesn't really matter. Just code the way that you feel comfortable with.